# Does the off-hand gauntlet of the Guardian Artificer gain the bonus Intelligence modifier?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

I'm trying to figure out in D&D 5e if an Artificer, choosing armorer and guardian, can add their intelligence modifier to attack and damage rolls with their off-hand gauntlet.

> Each model includes a special weapon. When you attack with that weapon, you can add your Intelligence modifier to the attack and damage rolls.

> **Thunder Gauntlets**

> Each of the armor's gauntlets.

Would the off-hand gauntlet be considered a part of the special weapon mentioned in the first quote to gain the bonus?

Answer (score 5):

#### D&D 5e does not distinguish between main and off hand.

Nowhere do the rules make a distinction between main hand and off hand.

#### The Thunder Gauntlets are not light melee weapons.

Now, for the purposes of two weapon fighting, you cannot use the gauntlets to make a bonus action attack, as two weapon fighting requires each weapon to be a light melee weapon:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a **light** melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different **light** melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

The gauntlets do not have the light property:

> Each of the armor’s gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while you aren’t holding anything in it.

#### They both get the bonus.

The “special weapon” of the Guardian Armorer is:

> Each of the armor’s gauntlets

Each gauntlet is itself a weapon, and each gets the bonus from your intelligence modifier to attack and damage rolls.

> Each model includes a special weapon. When you attack with that weapon, you can add your Intelligence modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, to the attack and damage rolls.

I know it says “weapon”, singular, and the guardian technically gets two, one for each hand.

Comment: Dual Wielder feat would solve the "can't minor action attack" problem.  Might not be worth it, but it would do the job.

Comment: @Ben I think it would be a pretty harsh DM that wouldn't let it work with thunder gauntlets, but Dual Wielder feat's description says "while you are wielding a separate melee weapon in each hand" and "even when the one-handed melee weapons you are wielding". The artificer isn't wielding anything *in their hand* with thunder gauntlets, technically, so the harsh DM would technically have a leg to stand on.

Comment: @Rykara Seems to me the gauntlets are simple melee weapons being held in hand.

Comment: As a DM, I personally would treat them that way as well (if nothing was being held) but thunder gauntlets' description does say they a gauntlet only count as a simple melee weapon "while you aren’t holding anything in it." I can see a player whose artificer is holding a holding a spell focus (tool) in one gauntlet trying to use Dual Wielder to gain +1 AC or use TWF to make an offhand attack. Though I suppose you could call the tool/focus an *improvised* melee weapon and allow the offhand gauntlet to satisfy all conditions for TWF plus Dual Wielder feat combo.

Comment: @Rykara It's true.  If you have a DM running at "I hate the players, and I don't mind if they know it" levels, they might contrive to forbid this rather unoptimal build choice.  That said, if you're dealing with *that* kind of DM, then you have larger problems than this.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, but not in the case of Two-Weapon Fighting

unless you have Two Weapon Fighting style.

Thomas Markov is correct in that 5e does not distinguish between your main hand and your off hand so the ability to use intelligence for attack and damage rolls applies to both.

"Off-hand weapon" is often a reference to the weapon used for the bonus action attack granted by Two-Weapon Fighting. Thomas is correct that you usually cannot use Two-Weapon Fighting with your thunder gauntlets because they are not light weapons.

You can, however, use Two-Weapon Fighting with your gauntlets of you take the Dual Wielder feat which allows the use of non-light weapons.
**You would not be able to add your Intelligence modifier to the damage of the bonus action attack granted by Two-Weapon Fighting.**

The Armorer feature states:

> you can add your Intelligence modifier, **instead of** Strength or Dexterity, to the attack and damage rolls.

Since you cannot add your Strength or Dexterity to the bonus action attack you also cannot substitute them with your Intelligence modifier.

Comment: It appears that you and the OP are quoting from different sources.  I wouldn't be surprised if yours was the more correct, but that's something that you should probably address.